# Данные не сохраняются

Tags: ado, база-данных, .net, ado.net, c#

Написал простую прогу на C# с использованием элементов ADO.NET. 
Из БД Access(формат "mdb") классом "OleDbDataAdapter" вытащил данные для определенной таблицы и "запихнул" в объект "DataGridView", создал BindingSource и BindingNavigator для управления записями. Возникла проблема с сохранением данных после измнения их в DataGridView – данные не хотят записываться в БД.
Привожу урывок кода:

```
...
private DataSet mainDS;
...
private void MakeTable(string tableName)
{
            //подключение и вытаскивание данных
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
            cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source= D:\KP\main.mdb;";
            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, cn);
            mainDS = new DataSet("main");
            dAdapt.Fill(mainDS, tableName);
            cn.Close();
        //тут наверно и ошибка
        resGrid.DataSource = mainDS.Tables[tableName];
        resGrid.Refresh();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = resGrid.DataSource;
        bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;

}
```

**Помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно! Заранее спасибо!**
*Пы.Сы: добавил к bindingNavigator1 кнопку, которая выполняет код: "mainDS.AcceptChanges();" и все-равно не пашет -(*

Comment: Вопрос актуален. Помогите плс.

Comment: Up! Очень нужна Ваша помощь!
"Это мне нуна будет пройтись по гриду и посмотреть какие записи были изменены, а потом и указать в Update для адптера?
"

Comment: "1.0k показов", "задан 12 часов назад", "отвечен 12 часов назад". Это вообще как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet.AcceptChanges помечает датасет как неизменённый.

Чтобы сохранить данные, нужно вызвать у адаптера Update. При этом на все несохранённые изменения сгенерятся команы обновления БД. Соответственно, если AcceptChanges вызвать перед этим, в БД тоже ничего не сохранится.

Comment: Это мне нуна будет пройтись по гриду и посмотреть какие записи были изменены, а потом и указать в Update для адптера?

Comment: AcceptChanges убрал.

Comment: Нет, адаптер сам это сделает. Надо один раз вызвать Update для всей DataTable